# Are there any tools to read the contents of dump files created during BSoD in Windows?

Tags: windows, bsod, dmp

Are there any tools that would help us read the contents in a Memory Dump files that is created when there is a BSoD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Debugging tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/) has a couple of useful debuggers for that.

If you're lucky all you need to do is load the dump file and type !analyze. If that doesn't do the trick, you have to examine the dump to find the reason for the crash.

Answer (score 0):

WinDBG - as the man says, in Debugging Tools for Windows.

WinDBG is difficult to use.  Steep and long learning curve.  It's not like Visual Studio, you know?